# Machine Learning with Limited Computational Resources

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, evolutionary-algorithm

I have an upcoming programming competition where we're designing AI players to compete against one another. The structure of our code is such that we have individual units that we can spawn from a headquarters, that can perform certain actions and interact under certain rules. For simplicity, I'll detail a specific agent, A, that's has the following inputs and actions:

```
Agent A:

Inputs: Position, Surrounding Tiles, Radio Message

Actions: Move, Attack, Build, Mine Resources, Broadcast Radio
```

The radio refers to a an integer signal that can be broadcast to other agents. This is a simplified version of what the units can actually do, but the question remains the same.

There is a key constraint on this problem, and that is that each agent has a limited number of cycles to perform calculations to determine its strategy. I would really like to try to implement some sort of machine learning in the determination of an optimized strategy, but a structure like a neural net over the input space (which can be relatively high-dimensional) leads to too complex of a calculation. In other words, I can't simply have each agent have its own neural network that is trained through some sort of genetic algorithm, (matrix multiplication is too expensive an operation). Other competitors are designing their agents by hand and give them a simple set of conditionals to determine actions (eg. if an enemy is close, move away from the enemy).

So my question is specifically if anyone has a suggestion on a way to implement a reduced form of the behavior, so that it's still able to try out different strategies, without hard-coding conditional statements, and without taking up demanding large computational resources. In other words, is there a way to generate a limited rule list of actions for a given input space such that the set of rules is trainable in any meaningful way?

Sorry if this question seems a bit ambiguous or unclear; I'm more than willing to specify additional details if there are any questions on what exactly I mean. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like the MIT BattleCode competition, is that correct? I once worked on an agent for the 2014 edition (though much later than the actual competition time, didn't participate or anything like that), and at least in that year the computational constraints were indeed very limiting; so limiting that almost any on-line algorithm can basically be thrown out of the window immediately.

Theoretically you could look into anytime algorithms, such as Monte-Carlo Tree Search, which in theory can be stopped at any time and return a result, where the quality of the result is expected to increase as the processing time increases. But, in this case you'd probably have to terminate the process so early that it wouldn't really give meaningful output either.

If you really want to go with Machine Learning approaches, I'd probably recommend going with the cheapest models possible at usage-time, which I suppose would be Decision Trees or Rule-learning systems. You would need a large dataset of various game states and ''correct'' moves to play in those situations in order to train such systems though. Do you have access to such a dataset, or have you thought about how to generate it? (note that this would also be an issue with a neural network).

Comment: This is exactly MIT BattleCode. These are some very interesting possibilities which I may want to look into more. My original plan to work with the neural network was to use a form of reinforcement learning over iteratively playing the AI against itself on my own machine. Looking into decision trees, I found one paper on using this method, but I'm not sure how viable it will be in our application. Here's a link if you're interested:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.06923v1.pdf

Regardless, this answer was really useful in giving me some potentially viable options, thanks!

Comment: On further inspection, the paper may not be incredibly applicable, because it still relies on queries to the environment about the correct response in a given timestep, which may be difficult to determine.

Comment: @AustinGarrett are you able to modify the rules of BattleCode locally, to give yourself much more processing time? (obviously not during the actual competition, but maybe for testing?) If so, you could give yourself a large amount of computation time, run games with a different algorithm, and create a database that way consisting of game states encountered and moves selected by that other, more computationally expensive algorithm. Then train a decision tree offline on that data, and use it online afterwards in the games with the real computation constraints